# Making boxplot using Seaborn

Tags: seaborn, boxplot

How to truncate x-label values to two decimal places while making boxplot using Seaborn? Looked at the Seaborn documentation, but struggling to find a solution.

Comment: You really need to add the code with some toy data to show the problem you are facing. And also show the resulting plot. How did you set the x-label values?  Are you talking about very high numbers? Or very small ones?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put any code, so I am assuming your problem is that your x-axis looks messy due to labels overlapping because they have decimal values up to 5 to 8 places.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
x=np.random.rand(10)

print(x)
# x looks like this [0.35216856 0.22145935 0.17762394 0.50507439 0.40720805 0.61499182 0.77852992 0.27904485 0.82737696 0.86285094]
ax = sns.boxplot(x=x)
xlabel=np.round(x, 2) # there may be better methods to round a numpy array
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabel) # input can be a list or array
plt.show()
```

Now the plot won't look messy.

Comment: You're redefining your `ax` variable on the fly, which doesn't make sense and is not a good practice.